# Inserting into sales_quote_item table

Tags: magento-1.9

I need to change the qty being inserted as I am using a third party for some products which annoying inserts 1 into the db everytime.

Where can I find all the relevant files for inserting into the sales_quote_item table

Answer (score 0):

You can check these rewrites
http://davidmann.solutions/change-product-quantity-added-cart-part-2-model-rewrite/

Or You can do observer
http://davidmann.solutions/change-product-quantity-added-cart-part-2-model-rewrite/
it is for price, but can be adjusted for qty